# convert Qt qml file to bit map image

Tags: c++, qt, qml, bmp

I want to take a qml I created in the QTCreator and transform it to a bmp image.
what I want in the bmp image is just the items I created.
I read about [grabWindow](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qscreen.html#grabWindow) but this is not realy what I want because it takes a snapshot of the screen and not creating bmp image with only the items in the qml.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From QML:

```
youritem.grabToImage(function(result) {
   result.saveToFile("something.bmp");
});
```

Although a bmp image is a bad idea, those things are huge. png is the best candidate for QML stuff, which is usually more "vector-y".

Comment: I actually was searching for something like this: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-rendercontrol-main-cpp.html but I find your answer really helpful so I marked it as answer. thanks